# Download multiple csv files in one zip folder using jsZIP in angular

Tags: angular, csv, angular7, jszip

Below is code in which i am creating data for csv file and downloading csv file in zip folder:

```
generateCSVfiles()
{
     this.studentdata.forEach(function (student)
{
      this.service.getStudentDetails(student.studentId).subscribe
          (res => {
            var dataSet =  JSON.parse (res);
            // start
            if (student.studentId == "Senior") {
             
               const header = ["studentId","studentName","studentaddress", "studentmarks", "studentgrade"];
              const replacer = (key, values) => values === null ? '' : values // specify how you want to handle null values here
              this.seniordata = dataSet.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
              this.seniordata.unshift(header.join(','));
              this.seniordata = this.seniordata.join('\r\n');
            }
            else  (student.studentId == "Junior") {
                const header = ["studentId","studentName","studentaddress", "studentmarks", "studentgrade"];
              const replacer = (key, values) => values === null ? '' : values // specify how you want to handle null values here
              this.juniordata = dataSet.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
              this.juniordata.unshift(header.join(','));
              this.juniordata = this.juniordata.join('\r\n');
               
            }
        this.downloadzip();
   }
}.bind(this)
}
   

public downloadzip()
{
    
     let zip = new JSZip();
      // Fill CSV variable
          // i am getting two separate zip file by below logic but need to 
         //implement  logic here to add two different file in one zip folder
      zip.file( 'Studentrecord'+'.csv', this.juniordata);
      zip.file( 'Studentrecord'+'.csv', this.seniordata);
    
    zip.generateAsync({
      type: "base64"
    }).then(function (content) {
      window.location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content ;
    });

}
```

Above code working fine and able to download csv file inside zip folder when we got response data for one of junior or Senior student at a time. but when we received both junior and senior data at time then it downloading different zip file or sometimes only one zip file getting generated. but i want both file in one zip folder. can someone guide me how to download different csv file in one zip folder.

```
this.studentdata =[{studentId: "Senior"
StudentName: "Rock"},{studentId: "Junior"
StudentName: "John"}]
```

this type of data available in mentioned variable

```
dataset = [{studentId: "Senior"
StudentName: "Rock",studentaddress:"US",studentmarks:"56",studentgrade:"A"},{studentId: "Junior"
StudentName: "John",studentaddress:"UK",studentmarks:"59",studentgrade:"B"}]
```

this type of data coming from json

Comment: In what condition you will receive data for both? your generateCSV method have if else statement. Only one of it will execute at a time. What's the response in case of both junior and senior?

Comment: Hey akash, i have updated question for better understanding , request you to don't concentrate data and condition because code is working fine on my system and am getting two separate different zip for both student but i want one zip file inside it should contain two csv file

Comment: can you add a similar dummy demo  on stackblitz ? it will be easy to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have not represented your question correctly. Appreciate if you create demo on stackbliz. Any how, this is due to your iteration does not wait for the each observable to complete before moving on to the next one and you have already told in comment that is true.

First of all you need to understand the concept of observable, promise in rxjs. Once you get proper understanding go through the some extra operators like merge, mergeAll, forkjoin etc https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Now comes to your question:
always use Promises for something like this, so below is an example of that, however, I'm sure there's an RXJS way to solve this as well, so you may want to explore that.

please go through http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html  for iterating async in series.

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

async generateCSVfiles() {
    //first iterate through everything in series
    await Bluebird.mapSeries(this.studentdata, (data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.service.getStudentDetails(student.studentId, student.StudentName).subscribe(res => {
                ...
                
                //once you finish your conditionals
                resolve();
            })
        });
    });


    //then, once complete, run download zip
    this.downloadzip();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give different file names, you are giving same filename to both kind of records and you can't have more than one file with same name in zip. If your goal is to have multiple excel sheets then this question is wrong. In that case you need to create excel like that.

Comment: hey @akash. I have tried with different file name also by assigning different variable and am able to download two different zip file instead of one so may be the issue here is that  iteration does not wait for the each observable to complete before moving on to the next one

Comment: for that we need actual code how you are dealing with your observables.